# Partner portal user unable to see notes created by Salesforce users on leads

Tags: partner-portal, notes

Leads have been passed from Salesforce users to Partner portal user but Partner portal users with Partner community license are unable to see notes created by Salesforce users on the lead however Partner portal user are able to create their own lead.

Comment: Whats OWD for leads in sharing settings for external user?

Comment: RWE. Partner portal users are able to create their own notes and can see each other's notes but can't see notes created by Salesforce full lic users on that particular Lead record.

Comment: Notes are treated as files and follow the same sharing rules of files, the default visibility is set to Internal Users and not AllUsers who have access to the record. However, this can be changed by writing a simple trigger.
Refer to Salesforce knowledge article -   
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000271156&language=en_US&type=1